# How to set default values in the Angular Timepicker?

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, timepicker

I am using the `NgbTimepickerModule` and this is my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div ngbDropdown>
  <input class="datepicker btn btn-link"  ngbDropdownToggle [value]="_value?(_value|date:'dd/MM/yy, HH:mm'):label">
      <div ngbDropdownMenu >
        <ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="date" (dateSelect)="getDatetime()"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" ></ngb-datepicker>

        <ngb-timepicker [ngModel]="time" (ngModelChange)="time=$event;getDatetime()"[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}" [hourStep]="time?.hour" [minuteStep]="time?.minute"></ngb-timepicker>
      </div>
      </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
  </form>
```

**I want time picker to have some default values in the HH and MM inputs and not be blank**

[image: Timepicker blank]

Here is the link to my [Stackblitz⚡](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9ukazv)

Also is it possible to add "required validation" on my datetime picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your stackblitz example and tweaked your code to achieve your requirements.

here is the codebase I tweaked.

```
// initialized time object from time: any to
time: { hour: number, minute: number};
```

In your if time not set condition added default time

```
if (!this.time) {
    value =  new Date().getDate()+'/'+new Date().getMonth()+'/'+new Date().getFullYear()+' '+ new Date().getHours() +':'+ new Date().getMinutes();
  
  // note this part  
  this.time = {
      hour: new Date().getHours(),
      minute: new Date().getMinutes()
    };
  }
```

Checkout the working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-npm94j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)